# What should I do about accidentally penetrating a septic field line?

Tags: plumbing, septic

I'm buying a piece of property and recently did a perc test on it in order to find a suitable place for a septic system. The current owner of the property installed a septic system a few years back, however, there are no records of this system at the county.

The county employee administrating the perc test wanted to check a bore sample of the septic field to see if it was properly installed. They used a hand auger to bore into the ground.

During this process, I noticed a small piece of plastic in the pile of dirt they removed from the hole. It was about the size of a quarter, pretty thin, and was white, with 2 black lines running across it on one side.

My assumption is the auger penetrated or skimmed a line from the septic field.

How concerned should I be if we use this septic field and a small piece of a line was skimmed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very. Septic drain lines have holes in them anyway, though the new hole is not going to be properly located. You could dig up and repair it if you are going to try and use the system. You can rent a camera to inspect inside the lines and assess the actual damage, or have someone else do that for you.

Comment: What are septic lines traditionally made of? Is it just normal pvc or something special?

Comment: @GaryHoliday clay pipe is often used but likely depends on location.

Comment: Here - very old systems may be clay with loose joints on the drain field side, but perforated plastic (various types of plastic) has been the norm for 50-odd years. Asbestos-cement might be seen in older systems, or (you hope not) "Orangeburg" - which is essentially tarpaper pipe and known for failing.